# Update a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

```
QTableView *tableView = new QTableView();
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(15,4, this);
tableView->setModel(model);

model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem("#") );
model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem("col1") );
model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, new QStandardItem("col2") );

// update tableView

model->removeRows(0,model->rowCount());

QList<QStandardItem*> row1;
row1 << new QStandardItem("element 01") << new QStandardItem("element 02") << new QStandardItem("element 03");
model->appendRow( row1 );

QList<QStandardItem*> row2;
row2 << new QStandardItem("element 04") << new QStandardItem("element 05") << new QStandardItem("element 06");
model->appendRow( row2 );
```

The `tableView` will be frequently updated (all the content will be deleted and replaced).

what is the fastest way (less lines of code) to update this `QTableView`, maybe using some structure of data, and a `QStandardItemModel` method that handles directly this structure ?

something like:

```
model->setNewData( theNewData );
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to remove rows and add new  ones. You can just update the values for the current items like:

```
model->item(0, 0)->setData("element 01",Qt::DisplayRole);
model->item(0, 1)->setData("element 02",Qt::DisplayRole);
model->item(0, 2)->setData("element 03",Qt::DisplayRole);

model->item(1, 0)->setData("element 04",Qt::DisplayRole);
model->item(1, 1)->setData("element 05",Qt::DisplayRole);
model->item(1, 2)->setData("element 06",Qt::DisplayRole);
```

Comment: When I tried this I get error: C2039: 'item': is not a member of 'QSqlTableModel'. What could be wrong?